# PCE-AC55BT B1 Linux Compatible?

Tags: 16.04, wireless, kernel, bluetooth, asus

I have Ubuntu Mate Linux 16.04 with linux kernel 4.10.0-42. i want to purchase the  PCE-AC55BT B1 by asus. It says it's compatible with linux but it doesn't specify which kernel version and linux distros. Is anyone using this Wifi+Bluetooth adapter on linux. And if so which version kernel and distro are you using

Comment: According to this https://wikidevi.com/wiki/ASUS_PCE-AC55BT_B1 yes, it should work with any current release. But hardware recommendations are off topic.

Answer (score 5):

According to the contents of [ASUS's driver package DR_PCE_AC55BT_B1_Wifi.zip](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/wireless/PCE-AC55BT_B1/DR_PCE_AC55BT_B1_Wifi.zip) this adapter is based on Intel chipset (Intel Wireless WiFi Link 8260 AC Adapter), which is well supported on Ubuntu.

It seems that all you need is to copy firmware `iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode` to `/lib/firmware/`. But on my 16.04.3 LTS this file is preinstalled and has the same MD5 checksum. So it would work out-the-box.

Answer (score 0):

I use this adapter myself. WiFi works but Bluetooth does not.